# Is adding noindex for new product pages a good idea?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, ecommerce, noindex

When adding batch products to an eCommerce website, is it a good idea to initially have *noindex* on the product page?

After manually reviewing individual products, should I remove the *noindex* tag?

Batch add will only add manufacturer description and specs, so it will result in duplicate content found on lots of websites selling the same items.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. It is better to be cautious than regret not being so in the end. Your idea of manual reviews of pages sounds very reasonable to me.

Comment: It is an excellent idea...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how many products you have.

But here few basic standard practices.

- If content is unoriginal and less than 300words; mark for no-index and no-follow.
- If content is original and less than 300words; mark for no-index and do-follow
- If content is original and more than 300words; mark for index and do-follow.

Suggestions on improving
- Add UGC content
- Hire writers and copyeditors to write original content

Comment: how adding a nofollow will help for the first point? can you give a example? regards

Comment: "Nofollow" provides a way for webmasters to tell search engines "Don't follow links on this page". Not a hard-rule, but also no point in passing negative link juice to other pages, if most content on the page is duplicated. Search engines sees a page as content and links. Content to index and links to follow. But if content is less and low quality, the link juice is less or negative (after penguin and panda).